# Sending SOAP requests using libcurl as XML file

Tags: c, xml, rest, soap, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl to do a SOAP http post to a web service. I have the SOAP requests already formed in XML files which I generate. Now I need to transefer these XML files to the webservice. N.B. I'm pretty new to writing webservices (especially in C).

Is there a way do send the SOAP requests straight from the XML file using libcurl? Or do I have to read the contents into a string? I'm restricted to using the C programming language to complete the task.

I've been looking through documentation and different code snippets but I can't seem to locate anything to do the requested. This curl link does it through a string http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html). FOr speed purposes I would greatly prefer to not have to pass to a string before sending it.

Comment: the 'void *userp' from the callback is what you provide in the DATA-part. It may be a 'FILE *' for example.

Answer (score 2):

you use curl_easy_setopt()? then you may want to take a look at CURLOP_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.

Comment: I have been trying to accomplish this using this method without much luck. I haven't even been able to perform the post using the following curl command: curl -v -X POST -d @file.xml "Content-Type:text/xml" "<ip>:80/service"

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this:
  * Get [TinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/),  load the file into a `TiXmlDocument` and use the `TiXmlPrinter` to get the XML file as string
  * Set the value of the string in the body of the post request( also, set headers, but they are the same as HTTP standard headers)
  * Take a look at [curl_easy_setopt()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) for callback and other stuff (:

Good Luck (:

Comment: Could you post a code example of how this works. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually .. do you have the headers written in the xml files? It's important. If so, TinyXML will not be used, as it will not recognize the headers and will not parse the document. Two options then.. but first of all - are the headers in the files?