# how to build a SOAP request in libcurl using C

Tags: c, soap, libcurl

i am new to libcurl and i want to create a SOAP request and send to web service. Can anyone send me some example or tutorial to read.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html), scroll down to the SOAP example by vivtek.

Comment: i went through that example, but it has its own header and I was not able to follow it properly. is there any other example or tutorial available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131946/sending-soap-requests-using-libcurl-as-xml-file

Comment: so the only way to accomplish this is writing the contents in xml files and then using curl to send it......